# Should I use present perfect simple or continuous in this phrase?

Tags: present-perfect

> This week I __________ (spend) a fortune because I have been going out every night so far.

In the previous sentence should I use present perfect simple or continuous? And why?

Personally I know that present perfect continuous takes precedence over simple if there are no reasons not to use it. Does the fact that "a fortune" is a quantity bring me to use the simple past?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use the present perfect continuous form "have been spending" in the sentence below. This is because you're still spending as indicated by "have been going" and "so far."

This week I __________ (spend) a fortune because I have been going out every night so far.

"A fortune" means "a lot of money" but it's meaning does not impact the need to use present perfect continuous.

Answer (score 0):

Not necessarily. What if it is Thursday and the person has been going out every night from the previous Friday until Wednesday. In that time he has spent a fortune (that money is gone) and now he is broke. The perfect continuous can be used for an action that has recently stopped and for quantity the present perfect is preferred.

On the other hand, if the person is making the statement while spending money on a night out the continuous would be the correct answer, I think.